# Add subitem to list view with String Array?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, arrays, subitem

BTW: This is for an Android app.
Hey guys, I have made a ListView, and I have managed to add data to it. Here some example code of what I have done so far.

```
String[] gameListFin;
ArrayList<String> gameList = new ArrayList<String>();

gameList.add(someData);
gameListFin = gameList.toArray(new String[gameList.size()]);

listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.shortcutsList);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, gameListFin));
```

This works as it should, I have a list view with the items I want. But I need to add a bit of extra data as a subitem to the list view, and I don't know how to do so. So I was wondering if I did this:

```
String[] gameListFin;
String[] extraFin
ArrayList<String> gameList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> extra = new ArrayList<String>();

gameList.add("1");
gameList.add("2");
gameList.add("3");
gameList.add("4");
extra.add("1 extra");
extra.add("2 extra");
extra.add("3 extra");
extra.add("4 extra");
gameListFin = gameList.toArray(new String[gameList.size()]);
extraFin = extra.toArray(new String[extra.size()]);
```

How could I set it so that the String Array extraFin can be set to sub items of the list view, so it would say

```
1
1 extra
----------
2
2 extra
----------
3
3 extra
----------
4
4 extra
```

Thanks for your time and help, help will be greatly apriciated. zeokila

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916834/android-adding-listview-sub-item-text

Answer (score 2):

You need to use expandableListView instead of listView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 1):

You must learn custom Adapter to show custom data for ListView

Here you will find a good example

http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/