# Android List Widget Text Size / Appearance

Tags: java, android, listview, widget, android-widget

So I have a widget that has a list with a textview inside each item. I want to have some items have bold text and others to not.

Right now this is what I have in my ListProvider:

```
@Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
                context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_list_item);

        ListObject listObject = listObjectList.get(position);

        //get whether item is a item or title
        if(listObject.getClass().equals(ListItem.class)) {
            //list item
            ListItem listItem = (ListItem) listObject;
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, listItem.text);
        }else{
            //list title
            ListTitle listTitle = (ListTitle) listObject;
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, listTitle.title);
        }

        return remoteView;
    }
```

widget_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/widgetTextColor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/widget_item_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widget_item_padding" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/widgetTextColor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/widget_item_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widget_item_padding"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It works but the list gets all scrambled up and messed up when scrolling because of the two textviews in the widget_list_item (text, title). Is there a simple way to change a specific item's text boldness / appearance (not size)?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916834/android-adding-listview-sub-item-text) is what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I'm using a widget listview. It works differently.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it on my own! Super simple! I just set the unused text view to blank text.

```
if(listObject.getClass().equals(ListItem.class)) {
            //list item
            ListItem listItem = (ListItem) listObject;
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "");
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, listItem.text);
        }else{
            //list title
            ListTitle listTitle = (ListTitle) listObject;
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "");
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, listTitle.title);
        }
```