# Change String-Array in Strings.xml to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm developing an Android app. I need to convert a string array into an ArrayList. I've read up on this, and all have cases where you add the values to the array in the java file. I have declared the string-array in the strings.xml file. My string-array is here:

```
<string-array name="Lines">
    <item>Red Line</item>
    <item>Blue Line</item>
    <item>Orange Line</item>
    <item>Green Line</item>
    <item>Brown Line</item>
    <item>Purple Line</item>
    <item>Pink Line</item>
    <item>Yellow Line</item>
</string-array>
```

I need to convert Lines into ArrayList. If I use this

```
List<String> Lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to declare the ArrayList, how can find the array list by ID, and store that as Lines?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Try this;

```
List<String> Lines = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Lines));
```

and this for kotlin:

```
val Lines = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Lines).toList()
```

Comment: What if i want an ArrayList insted of a List?

Comment: @G.Ciardini              `ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Lines)));`

Answer (score 5):

If anybody wondering how to do the same in **kotlin**

```
val universities = arrayListOf<String>(*resources.getStringArray(R.array.universities))
```

`universities` will be `ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 4):

In strings.xml,  add string array

```
<string-array name="dashboard_tags">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Settings</item>
</string-array>
```

In your .java class access the string array like

```
List<String> tags = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dashboard_tags));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best practice without any warning

Add string array to arraylist:

```
Collections.addAll(Lines, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Lines));
```

To add one ArrayList to another:

```
newList.addAll(oldList);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
String[] parityArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayName);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)