# Android Listview add item and subitem programmatically

Tags: android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Adding Subitem to a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587301/android-adding-subitem-to-a-listview)

I have 2 arrays - Namearray & companyarray.
I want to display it in the listview.
I have managed to display the names in the list by using the following code:

```
ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Namearray);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But how do I add a Sub Item to the list as a Company Name.

After following Sai Geetha's blog - I came out with following -
But the list is appearing empty - it shows 2 black lines with no text on them.
My Activity background is blue and I have checked in custom_row_view that the textview textcolor is black.
Have I missed anything?

```
if(cur!=null && cur.getCount()>0)
        {
        List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
         Log.w("count=","ct="+cur.getCount() );
        for (int i=1;i<=cur.getCount();i++) {
            Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
            Log.w("name=",cur.getString(0) );
            Log.w("compname=",cur.getString(1) );
            datum.put("Name",cur.getString(0));
            datum.put("Company", cur.getString(1));
            data.add(datum);
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                                                 R.layout.custom_row_view,
                                                  new String[] {"Name", "Company"},
                                                  new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
                                                             android.R.id.text2});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        cur.close();
        }
```

Comment: Hi check the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916834/android-adding-listview-sub-item-text http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

Comment: your code appears fine , are you using white background color for the list